# Magento 2 How to create and load custom route page

Tags: custom, 404-page, redirect-url, router

I want to add a custom redirect type 410 in URL redirect. I have added this in admin section and configured some pages with 410 redirect.

Now I want to check the redirect type is 410 and if it is 410 I want to display a custom page or text like 404 page. I didn't want to redirect to another URL. I want the same functionality as 404 page.
How can I do it?